# Swift - 4 - Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10cfb1840) to 'NSString' (0x10c0824a8)

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10cfb1840) to
>   'NSString' (0x10c0824a8)

on this line of code:

```
fkprofession = (pickOption[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]["id"] as? String)!
```

pickOption is defined as:

```
var pickOption = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pickOption[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]["id"]` is not a `String`, it's a `NSNumber`. So cast it as an Int maybe? Or as a NSNumber, then get its intValue (or floatValue, or I don't know), and then convert it into a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: The value for key `id` is a number (`Int` or maybe `Double`)

You can read a *could-not-cast* error always as

> Could not cast value of the ***right*** type to **my proposed *wrong*** type

```
fkprofession = pickOption[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]["id"] as! Int
```

Or if you need a string

```
fkprofession = String(pickOption[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]["id"] as! Int)
```

Comment: I think that `fkprofession` is a String, so a minor change.